# Get webpage content from silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I want to use Silverlight to parse http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://bing.com/ and see if "bing.com" is up. Is this possible in a Silverlight site (running in-browser with no elevated trust)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you can get their participation- they'd need a clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml that allows your hosting domain (or all domains) access. Without that, you're pretty much hosed for *direct* access from Silverlight without elevated trust.

That said, you could easily have the server that's hosting your Silverlight xap make the outbound connection via a service call, then proxy the result back to a Silverlight client.